# Ubuntu 14.04.3 Dual boot - No grub menu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, boot-repair

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 in a partition along side Windows 10. Grub menu doesn't show up, it directly boots to Windows 10.

Here's my boot-repair info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12864055/

What do I do to get the Grub menu?

Comment: Is Fast Startup turned off in Windows 10 and is Secure Boot turned off in the BIOS? http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Yes, and also executed this command "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"

Comment: That's telling me you have MBR and not GPT, which means that there is no `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Comment: Run `boot-repair` again

Comment: Done, everything same as before nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that you have dual booted correctly, you can try this:-*

**1. Go to boot menu option(by Pressing F9 or similar keys)
2. Choose Ubuntu**

*I was having the same issue in my HP Pavilion Laptop.
Grub didn't showed up. Method above worked for me.*